# Is there a way to verify if the User's time and date is correct in microsoft access vba?

Tags: vba, database, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am creating a database which updates all information automatically based on the User's current date.
But there is an issue, it means that if the User has a wrong date settings, it means the whole system in compromised. The only solution I thought of was to get the User's regional setting and the user's time zone and use that to determine if the time and date is wrong so the database doesn't update. But so far I have found NO WAY to get the user's timezone and regional setting using microsoft access. Can someone help me please?
I have found no function or way to get those settings of the User in Access. The closest  I got to that was Application.LanguageSettings  .I am really lost here.

Comment: There is something wrong here. "The User's current date" must be the same for ALL users. So there is no "User's current date", just a "current date".

Comment: But if the current user's system date & time _can_ be different, then you need _both_ solutions below to check: get UTC to check against the system and use timezone information to adjust any local time to UTC. UTC is the gold standard for time.

Comment: It doesn't add any real info to check the machine's current timezone, as this can easily be adjusted by the user.

Comment: wow. that actually worked. I JUST used the wscript.shell to check for the timezone. The software needs to work with only one user. So if the timezone is not set to the the right one, it should prompt the user and only open the software in read mode. Cool enough?

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the UTC time from a remote API:

```vb
' Retrieves the current UTC date and time from a remote source.
' Split seconds (milliseconds) are rounded to the second like VBA.Now does.
'
' Documentation:
'   http://worldtimeapi.org/
'
' 2018-09-11. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateUtcNow() As Date

    ' ServiceUrl for time service.
    Const ServiceUrl        As String = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/etc/utc.txt"
    
    ' Fixed constants.
    Const Async             As Boolean = False
    Const StatusOk          As Integer = 200
    Const UtcSeparator      As String = "datetime: "
    Const IsoSeparator      As String = "T"
    
    ' Engine to communicate with the service.
    Dim XmlHttp             As XMLHTTP60
    
    Dim ResponseText        As String
    Dim UtcTimePart         As String
    Dim DateTimePart        As String
    Dim SplitSeconds        As Double
    Dim CurrentUtcTime      As Date
  
    On Error GoTo Err_DateUtcNow
    
    Set XmlHttp = New XMLHTTP60
    
    XmlHttp.Open "GET", ServiceUrl, Async

    XmlHttp.send

    ResponseText = XmlHttp.ResponseText
    If XmlHttp.status = StatusOk Then
        UtcTimePart = Split(ResponseText, UtcSeparator)(1)
        DateTimePart = Replace(Left(UtcTimePart, 19), IsoSeparator, " ")
        SplitSeconds = Val(Mid(UtcTimePart, 20, 7))
        CurrentUtcTime = DateAdd("s", SplitSeconds + 0.5, CDate(DateTimePart))
    End If
    
    DateUtcNow = CurrentUtcTime

Exit_DateUtcNow:
    Set XmlHttp = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_DateUtcNow:
    MsgBox "Error" & Str(Err.Number) & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Web Service Error"
    Resume Exit_DateUtcNow

End Function
```

Then check if the date/time from `Now()` is within +/- 12 hours of this.

This requires a reference to `Microsoft XML, v6.0`.

Answer (score 3):

You can read regional settings from registry.

There are many ways to read from registry in VBA, I prefer to use `WScript.Shell`, but others use WinAPI (more complicated, but WScript.Shell can be blocked)

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\TimeZoneKeyName")
```

For more detailed time zone information, you can use WinAPI.

```
Public Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type


Public Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(64) As Byte
    StandardDate As SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(64) As Byte
    DaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Const TIME_ZONE_ID_STANDARD = 1
Const TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT = 2

Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByRef lpTimezoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Public Function GetBiasInHours() As Long
    Dim tzi As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim IsDST As Long
    IsDST = GetTimeZoneInformation(tzi)
    Dim Bias As Long
    If IsDST = TIME_ZONE_ID_DAYLIGHT Then
        Bias = tzi.DaylightBias / 60
    Else
        Bias = tzi.Bias / 60
    End If
    GetBiasInHours = Bias
End Function
```

The bias can be used to calculate time to UTC time. How to do these calculations is described in [the documentation on the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-time_zone_information). Of course, you can also use the StandardName and DaylightName to check if the timezone is set as expected. You cast these to strings with the following code:

```
Dim StandardNameString As String
StandardNameString = tzi.StandardName
StandardNameString = Left(StandardNameString, InStr(StandardNameString & vbNullChar, vbNullChar) - 1)
```

Comment: OMG! I didn't even know that this even existed in the first place.I don't even understand half of the WinAPI code that you placed over there. The only one I could use that actually worked was the "WScript.Shell" .  Thank you soo soo much! But I wish I could understand how the WinAPI worked. And how did you get soo good at this? This is amazing honestly. Thank you soo much Man!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, learning WinAPI is tough. It helps a lot if you have a background in C or start learning C, since WinAPI is a C API that VBA can call. If you can write C, and know how the VBA types translate to C types, it's not hard, but those requisites are both quite challenging.